# How to serialize content of a Map with their toString?

Tags: java, scala, json4s

I tried to to use json4s native library. Here is how I use it:

```
Builder b = new JsonMessageBuilder();
Map<String, List<Object>> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m2.put("e", Arrays.asList(new StringBuilder(123)));
b.message(JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m2).asScala());

public static class Test{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Where

```
class JsonMessageBuilder{
    def message[A <: AnyRef](a: A) = println(Serialization.write(a))
}
```

But the code prints this:

```
{"e":[{}]}
```

How to force serialization of `toString` result in a map? I want to have

```
{"e":["test"]}
```

Comment: Is that a typo? Did you mean: new StringBuilder ("123")

Comment: Why you expect this output? Your `Test` class is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the issue is that you are not instantiating your StringBuilder correctly i.e. not enclosing the argument 123 in quotes. Thats why you are getting an empty stringbuilder. The serialization is happening correctly as the `{"e":[{}]}` is printed. Try this:

```
m2.put("e", Arrays.asList(new StringBuilder("123")));
```